# QBFC Billadd GUID Error

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am new to C# and QBFC13 code and I'm trying to add a bill from [code I found on the intuit developer site under the BillAdd section](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html).

The `BillAddRq.ExternalGUID.SetValue(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());` is throwing a error:

> Invalid GUID format. Must use zero for Custom Fields, or a GUID generated with GuidGen.exe for private data extensions.

I’ve tried:

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B");
// MessageBox to see that it creates the number
MessageBox.Show("guid", guid); 
BillAddRq.ExternalGUID.SetValue(guid);

BillAddRq.ExternalGUID.SetValue(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
And 
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("0");
```

And those throw:

> QB Test 8-14-2014.vshost.exe - No Disk "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive F."

How can I resolve these errors?

Answer (score 6):

Using your first string attempt is the correct format for the `GUID`. I tested using `GUID.NewGuid().ToString("B")` and was able to get a  `GUID` that works when adding a bill.

Because you're getting an error about there being no disk in the drive, it sounds like something else is causing the error. I would step through the code and find the exact place that causes the error as it probably has nothing to do with the `GUID`.

Here's a simple example that I did using a sample file in QuickBooks:

```
QBSessionManager SessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
SessionManager.OpenConnection2("GUIDTest","GUIDTest", ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
SessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);

IMsgSetRequest MsgRequest = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
MsgRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

IBillAdd add = MsgRequest.AppendBillAddRq();
add.ExternalGUID.SetValue(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
add.VendorRef.FullName.SetValue("A Cheung Limited");
add.TxnDate.SetValue(DateTime.Today);
IExpenseLineAdd line = add.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
line.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Travel & Lodging");
line.Amount.SetValue(100.00);

IResponse response = sessionManager.DoRequests(MsgRequest).ResponseList.GetAt(0);
MessageBox.Show(response.StatusMessage);
```

Comment: Not quite sure why the ("B") option ha to be there, but it does and YAY! You're my hero!